# Funciones javascript porblema masMenos

Tags: javascript

Estoy teniendo un problema con el siguiente codigo, el resultado me tira undefined y no entiendo porque. Les paso el enunciado del ejercicio
"Necesitamos una función masMenos que reciba un array y devuelva otro con los siguientes tres números:

En la primera posición, la fracción de números que son positivos
En la segunda posición, la fracción de números que son cero
En la última posición, la fracción de números que son negativos
Por ejemplo, masMenos([1, 2, 0, -1]) debería devolver [0.5, 0.25, 0.25], dado que hay 50% de positivos, 25% de ceros, y 25% de negativos."

```js
function masMenos(unArray){
    let positivos = 0;
    let negativos = 0
    let ceros = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++){
        if (unArray[i] > 0){
            positivos += 1;
        } else if (unArray[i]< 0){
            negativos += 1;
        }else{
            ceros += 1
        }
    }
    let suma = positivos + negativos + ceros;
    let fraccion = [positivos/suma, negativos/suma, ceros/suma];
    return fraccion
}

console.log(masMenos[1,2,0,-1])
```

Comment: La variable `sumas` no existe. Eso afecta la última división.

Comment: La variable `fracccion` es la que estas declarando, pero retornas `fraccion`, solo son palabras mal escritas, la función esta bien hecha.

Comment: @RodemilNavarro corregi ese error pero me sigue saliendo undefined a la hora de ejecutar el codigo

Comment: @Alfabravo corregi ese error y otro que tenia de escritura pero me sigue saliendo undefined a la hora de ejecutar el codigo

Comment: ¿No será `console.log(masMenos([1,2,0,-1]));`?...

Comment: Claramente me faltaban los parentesis en el console.log! Muchas gracias @Cris223511.dev

Answer (score 1):

A los métoidos les gusta cuando les das los parámetros dentro de los paréntesis, incluso si es un arreglo. Poner el nombre del método seguido de un arreglo no incluye el arreglo como parámetro :)

```js
function masMenos(unArray){
    let positivos = 0;
    let negativos = 0
    let ceros = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < unArray.length; i++){
        if (unArray[i] > 0){
            positivos += 1;
        } else if (unArray[i]< 0){
            negativos += 1;
        }else{
            ceros += 1
        }
    }
    let suma = positivos + negativos + ceros;
    let fraccion = [positivos/suma, negativos/suma, ceros/suma];
    return fraccion
}

console.log(masMenos(unArray=[1,2,0,-1]))
```